# No signing certificate iOS Distribution

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ipa, xcodebuild

I'm having trouble generating an IPA for OTA distribution.

We made an app for another company. That other company added me on their Enterprise account so that I could distribute using their signing identity.

**Creating the ipa with the command line**

Using the command xcodebuild, an archive I made using xcode where I put the team as that other company's team, and a plist stating I was building for Enterprise,  I get this error:

> No valid iOS Distribution signing identities belonging to team [company team id of the other company] were found.

**Using XCode**

I tried doing it with XCode as well, unchecking the "Automatically manage signing" in Xcode and selecting the other company, and then I get these errors:

> No signing certificate "iOS Distribution" found.
>
> No "iOS Distribution" signing certificate matching team ID [other company's team ID] with a private key was found."

Is there something I should download from the developer account? (I already downloaded all the certificates... I think)
I can't revoke the distribution certificate they have, as it is not my company and it might create problems for them.

Thanks.

Comment: Check keychain if it includes certificate and private key of it, if its not there you can create new distribution certificate or ask them to share certificate which includes private key details.

You can create multiple certificates, it will not impact on previous certificate.

Comment: Why did you uncheck "Automatically manage signing"? You should have just been able to select the team without unchecking that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you downloaded every certificate from the developer account, you only downloaded the public keys, what you need to do is one of two solutions that I know of:

Either ask the other company to export one of the private key from one of their machine, and you can import it into your keychain, only then when you'll try to sign your app, it will look for private half of the certificate in the keychain and it will find it (hence the error you're getting, no certificate with PRIVATE KEY was found).

Or, you'll have to create a new production Certificate using a certificate generated from your own keychain (and a provisioning that goes with it...).

Comment: How would I create a new production certificate using a certificate generated from my own keychain?

Comment: You can do so by login into your client apple developer account and then in the identifier and certificat section choose certificat and you can follow through.

Comment: After much back and forth, they finally sent me the private key with which I was able to create the ipa.
Thanks!

Comment: You re welcome, and i can really relay to those back and forth by the way :)
glad i could ve been of assistance. cheers